# Trimming array values

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

I know var_dump($array) trims the array content & print it. but I want to skip the print part. What should I do? Should I use some other function

Answer (score 6):

Use [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

```
$trimmed = array_map('trim', $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find something here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php